# How to use new Copernicus EU-DEM data in GDAL

Tags: gdal

I use the old Copernicus EU-DEM TIF files for determining my height over ground. These files are not anymore available on Copernicus' sites. The following GDAL utility call to the old files provides the correct answer.

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly E30N20.TIF -1.4921262475286496 43.28123094994876
```

101.241691589355

New files are available now from Eurostat. Applying the same command to the new file, it fails.

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly g90Aur.tif -1.4921262475286496 43.28123094994876
```

> ERROR 1: TIFFFillTile:Read error at row 4294967295, col 4294967295,
> tile 502221; got 0 bytes, expected 156013 ERROR 1:
> TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed. ERROR 1: g90Aur.tif, band 1: IReadBlock
> failed at X offset 471, Y offset 446: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.

I have no clou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that this has anything to do with the change in source. It's probably a corrupt/incomplete download. It would help if you would provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the very least share what your old and new sources are, otherwise it turns into a guessing game.

For exampple, downloading the relevant tile (`10_DEM_y40x-10.tif`) from:
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/elevation/copernicus-dem/elevation

For me returns:

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly 10_DEM_y40x-10.tif -1.4921262475286496 43.28123094994876
101.735122680664
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I downloaded the E30N20.TIF from Copernicus. As I said, these files are not anymore on the Copernicus web site. I downloaded the new files from here: [named hyperlinks](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/elevation/eu-dem/eu-dem-dd)

Comment: With the link you gave me, it works, again.